# How to get the key of a java.util.map from the Value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I have a map of `Map<String, Integer>`. I need to sort the values and retrieve the key of the first value after sorting.

I did something like this `Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(map.values());`.
Now the values are sorted, How do I get the key of the first element in the sorted values.

I will also welcome a better way of achieving this.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where a *value* is mapped to more than one *key*? In a map, keys are guaranteed to be unique, but values are not.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider `TreeSet<Map.Entry>` rather than `TreeSet<Integer>` (filling it with the `entrySet` from your existing map), and using a `Comparator<Map.Entry>`. Then in your `Comparator<Map.Entry>` implementation, compare based on the values. Then you still have the keys and values associated with one another.

Comment: How do I use a `Comparator<Map.Entry>` and `entrySet()` at the same time since the constructor of `TreeSet` can only take either.

Comment: @erictesting: You construct with the comparator, then repeatedly add from `entrySet` in an enhanced `for` loop. E.g. (after construction) `for (Map.Entry entry : originalMap.entrySet()) { treeSet.add(entry); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is ill-defined. What if two keys map to the same value--which one of them should you retrieve?

The best you can do given the map you have is to use `entrySet()` rather than `values()`, which pairs up the keys with their values. You could then sort the `Entry` objects by value and retrieve the proper keys.

**However**, it would likely be far better to simply keep another `Map` in the "opposite direction" in the first place. Presumably you'd populate this one at the same time as you populate the first one, and then you could use the second `Map` to quickly retrieve "keys" from "values." Something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> originalMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<Integer, String> reverseLookup = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// Populate both maps at the same time, with the same data (but reversed)...

for (Integer i : originalMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(reverseLookup.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the key of the first element in the sorted values.

Not the most efficient way, but you could call this method with the first element of your sorted `Set`. **This method assumes you have non-null values in your `Map`.**

```
private String getKeyForValue(Integer value, Map<String, Integer> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == value) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value " + value + " was not found in the map.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(map.values());

Iterator iter = set.iterator();

Integer firstValue = (Integer) iter.next();
String firstKey = null;
for(String key : map.keySet())
{
  if(map.get(key) == firstValue)
  {
    firstKey = key;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Map.entrySet(), it contains the values together with their keys.

Comment: but you wouldn't be able to distinguish which one is the key of the first value, since the values are sorted after taken out from the map, right?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to distinguish equal values, but apart from that, you can just iterate over the set until you find your value!?

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // do your sorting
}
// fetch the first entry here
entry.getKey();
```

Comment: why would OP do sorting in a loop?

Comment: it is just an example for using Map.Entry. Everything else is not significant, here only to show an example.